# Timeout error occurred for capturing an image from photo stream in IMFSourceReaderCallback::OnReadSample?

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I'm using source reader technique to take a snap from photo stream from the USB camera device. Inconsistently I'm getting a timeout error(ERROR_TIMEOUT). 
Moreover, IMFSample contains NULL value and dwStreamFlags parameter returns MF_SOURCE_READERF_ERROR if above issue occurred.

**Using below code to trigger the still:**

```
   hr = pAttribute->SetUINT32(MF_DEVICESTREAM_TAKEPHOTO_TRIGGER,1L);
   if(FAILED(hr)){  goto done;}

   // Ask for the still sample. '1' is PhotoStream index.
   hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
   if(FAILED(hr)) { goto done;}
```

This code is working for most of the resolution.

Past 2 weeks I was struggling with this issue. Am I doing anything wrong? Could you please give me an idea/guidelines to sort out this issue?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Anyone can you help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: What happens if you ignore the timeout error and issue another ReadSample after that?

Comment: VuVirt Thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay. I'm receiving same ERROR_TIMEOUT error if issue another ReadSample.

Comment: You can call it in a loop when ERROR_TIMEOUT error occurs to see if it will make any difference.

Comment: I called it in while loop and the result are ERROR_TIMEOUT. The call does not come out from the loop and my UI got hanged.

Comment: So you receive ERROR_TIMEOUT from a ReadSample call, right? What is the exact HRESULT value?

Comment: Yes, VuVirt. I'm receiving HRESULT Value as 0x800705b4.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to try to recreate the source reader when this error occurs and issue another ReadSample on the new reader.

Comment: Yes, VuVirt. I'm recreating the new source reader and issuing another ReadSample then its working fine for me. Actually, I have explored this error in 2ways: I) Capture still If my USB connected in USB 2.0 port...II) Video streaming in one format(YUY2) and Photostream in another format(MJPG)...Do you have any idea for above two scenarios?

Comment: No, I have never seen this error before. I think it might be driver related and maybe it's a temporary error.

Comment: Thank you VuVirt. I think it is not a driver problem since I'm able to capture a still image if USB Camera is connected in USB 3.0& 2.0 Port using Directshow technology. I think the problem is in Source Reader Media Foundation.

Comment: Maybe you can try with IMFMediaSession to see if it works.

Comment: I have tried to take still using IMFMediaSession but I couldn't achieve it. Can you please suggest some idea/sample code to take still image using media session.

Comment: I think you need to build the topology, then set the MF_DEVICESTREAM_TAKEPHOTO_TRIGGER attribute to the IMFMediaSource, after that maybe perform scrubbing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee892370(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: You will also need this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh184779(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your valuable ideas, VuVirt. Six Months back, I have implemented image capture using media session but have faced some problem with it. Problems are: 1) Inconsistently trigger will not work on some PC...2) I have to re-initialize the media session after complete the still trigger. For this reason, I moved to SourceReader technique.

Comment: Any idea on this issue, Vuvrit?

Comment: Not really. As a last resort you might try to do it low level by working with the IMFMediaSource directly, by handling all the events yourself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703106(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have reported this media session issue to Microsoft. They suggest me to use source reader technique to solve all this problem but am facing the issue in source reader also.